# Whitespace in multiple parameters for PEP8

Tags: python, pep8

I was wondering how should I use whitespaces when calling a method with multiple complex parameters.

`x = func(mid+1, end, current*2 + 1, q_start, q_end)`
or

`x = func(mid+1, end, current*2+2, q_start, q_end)`

Just like above, which one is better?

Comment: Your arguments are expressions. Operators in expressions are surrounded by spaces according to PEP 8.

Answer (score 0):

PEP8 doesn't say anything about this particular situation. The closest it comes is the part that starts *"If operators with different priorities are used"* under [this section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations).

Comment: Yeah, it did not talk about such a case. That's why I would ask which one is actually better.